# Hibernate Filter by enum type after join

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have 2 hibernate entities TariffDescription and Tariff,
TariffDescription contains a list of tariffs. I need to filter tariffs by sellType and catalogEntryId.

SellType is an enum. And when I execute HQL:

```
SELECT t FROM Tariff t WHERE t.catalogEntryId = :catalogEntryId AND
t.sellType=:sellType
```

Everything works fine.

But when I'm trying to execute that HQL:

```
SELECT td FROM TariffDescription td JOIN td.tariffs t where
t.catalogEntryId = :catalogEntryId AND t.sellType=:sellType
```

It returns all types of sellType.
It really looks like a bug, but I haven't found something like that on bug trackers.

The version of hibernate: 4.2.18.Final.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN FETCH fixed my issue. Looks like tariffs was lazy loaded and hibernate couldn't apply causes in where.